# ¿Cómo capturar los datos de un formulario con JavaScript en Symfony?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony4

> Cree mi formulario en mi controlador y puedo registrar datos de manera
> normal, pero no puedo manejar los campos con JavaScript.

- **CREE MI FORMULARIO DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA EN MI CONTROLADOR:**

  ```
    $form =$this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('tipo_comprobante')
        ->add('serie_comprobante')
        ->add('num_comprobante')
        ->add('fecha_hora',DateType::class)
        ->add('estado')
        ->add('tipo_pago')
        ->add('total_compra')
        ->add('deuda')
        ->add('cantidad', NumberType::class)
        ->add('precio_compra', NumberType::class)
        ->add('Guardar',SubmitType::class) 
    ->getForm();
  ```
- **TRATE DE "PERSONALIZAR" LOS CAMPOS EN EL TEMPLATE DE LA SIGUIENTE FORMA:**

  ```
  {{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
        <label>DETALLE SALIDA</label>
        <div class="col" name="ccantidad_ingreso" id="ccantidad_ingreso">
             {{ form_row(form.cantidad) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col" name="pprecio_compra" id="pprecio_compra">
             {{ form_row(form.precio_compra) }}
        </div>
        <label> Medicamento </label>                     
        <input type="text" name="z" id="z">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8">
               <button type="button" id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   {{ form_end(form) }}
  ```
- **TRATE DE MANIPULARLO CON JAVASCRIPT:**

  ```
  {% block javascripts %}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $('#bt_add').click(function()
   {
        agregar();
    });
  });

  function agregar()
    {
        //$("#").val()
        precio_compra = document.getElementById("pprecio_compra").value;
        cantidad_ingreso = document.getElementById("ccantidad_ingreso").value;
        z = document.getElementById("z").value;

        console.log(precio_compra);
        console.log(cantidad_ingreso); 
        console.log(z);
    }
  </script>

  {% endblock %}
  ```
- **MI PROBLEMA:**

> No puedo capturar los valores del formulario que cree en el
> controlador, pero si captura los valores del "input" que cree para
> probar y solo ignora los valores del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece error de tecleo, porque en _Symfony_ defines campos `precio_compra` y `cantidad`, pero en Javascript tratas de acceder con: `pprecio_compra` y `ccantidad_ingreso`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al llamar a `precio_compra = document.getElementById("pprecio_compra").value` estas cogiendo el value del div en lugar del input. Lo que necesitas es hacerle un `.value` del elemento input.

Utiliza la consola del navegador para saber que nombre de clase o id tiene realmente, ya que symfony crea sus propios valores para los atributos `class` y `name`.

Otra de las opciones que tienes es asignarle un id tu mismo al input en la vista utilizando los [Form Rendering Variables](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-variables):

```
{{ form_widget(form.campo1, { 'id': 'id_del_campo' }) }}
```

En tu caso como estas usando `form_row` sería así:

```
{{ form_row(form.campo1, { 'id': 'id_del_campo' }) }}
```

Lo mismo, pero añadiendo un `class` en lugar de un `id`:

```
{{ form_widget(form.campo1, { 'attr': { 'class': 'class_del_campo' } }) }}
```

Haciendo estos últimos evitas usar los `name` y `class` creados por el formulario de Symfony. De esta manera, cualquier script que tengas llamando a un `id` o un `class` del form seguirá funcionando incluso después de cambiar nombres de campos o el formulario en sí del `FormType`.

Comment: Gracias me funcionó. :D